# Powershell AD: Export CSV of specific fields based on CSV input of Names?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

I need to pass in a list of Users and get back a CSV with Name, SamAccountName, email

My Input CSV is as follows:

```
"John Doe"
"Jane Doe"
```

Here's the current code I'm using. I'm not sure what the problem is. The users actually do exist under the "DC" specified...

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Function Get-ADUsersDetailsCSV
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [String]$InCSV,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$OutCSV
    )

If($InCSV)
{
    If(Test-Path -Path $InCSV)
    {
        $USERS = Import-CSV $InCSV -Header Name
        $USERS|Foreach{Get-ADUser $_.Name -Properties * |Select Name, SAMAccountName, mail}|Export-CSV -Path $OutCSV

    } #End Test that the files exist

    Else
    {
        Write-Warning "Cannot find path '$InCSV' because it does not exist."
    }


} #End Ensure Input and Output files were provided

} #End Function Get-UsersDetailsCSV
```

Here's the error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'John Doe' under: 'DC=blah,DC=com'.
At U:\data\GetADUserInfo PS Script\GetADUsersDetailsCSV.psm1:19 char:28
+             $USERS|Foreach{Get-ADUser $_.Name -Properties * |Select Name, SAMAcc ...
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Name:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'John Doe' under: 'DC=blah,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: What fields are you wanting to get?

Comment: I need a final CSV with the Name, DisplayName, SamAccountName and email

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your feedback above, I will make changes to this answer.  However, there is no need to run Get-ADUser twice as you get both the name and email properties with the Get-ADUser object.

```
$user = Get-ADuser -Filer { Name -eq $Name }
```

In addition, you are able to pipe different objects together. Try this and see what you get

```
$ExportCSVPath = "C:\Exportedcsv.csv"
$users = (Import-Csv -Path $CsvFilePath) |  
    % {Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $_.DisplayName } | 
        Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName, mail } |
            Export-Csv $ExportCSVPath
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to use that in what I've got or if that's all I need?

Comment: $users will be an object that contains the SamAccountName and email address.  As well as the Display Name I believe.  Why don't you take that final pipe off and run it to see what happens.

Comment: PowerShell> (Import-Csv -Path .\namestest.csv) |  
        % {Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $_.DisplayName } | 
        Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName, mail }

Comment: Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. 
Specified method is not supported.
At line:3 char:32
+         Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName, mail }
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: what do you get with (Import-Csv -Path .\namestest.csv) | % {Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $_.DisplayName } }

Comment: Get-ADUser : Property: 'DisplayName' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
At line:1 char:41
+ (Import-Csv -Path .\namestest.csv) | % {Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $_.Display ...
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Property: 'DisplayName' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomOb 
   ject'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: (Import-Csv -Path $CsvFilePath).DisplayName | % {Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $_ } }

Comment: Get-ADUser : Variable: '_' found in expression: $_ is not defined.

Comment: what does this print out for you? (Import-Csv -Path $CsvFilePath).DisplayName

Comment: what are the fields in the CSV?  That should have printed the results

Comment: They are simply full names:
John Doe
Jane Doe